# Return only sequence of lines with specific patterns

Tags: bash, awk, grep

I get stuck with that task. I have list like that:

```
(...)
distName="PLMN-PLMN/MRBTS-4130/LNBTS-4130/FTM-1/IPNO-1"    
"btsId">4130<  
IpAddress">10.52.71.38</p> 
(...)
```

And I'm doing final file like that:

```
MRBTS-4130,4130,10.52.71.38
```

But sometimes few parts are missing and file looks like:

```
distName="PLMN-PLMN/MRBTS-4130/LNBTS-4130/FTM-1/IPNO-1"    
"btsId">4130<  
distName="PLMN-PLMN/MRBTS-4132/LNBTS-4132/FTM-1/IPNO-1" 
"btsId">4132<  
IpAddress">10.52.71.38</p>  
distName="PLMN-PLMN/MRBTS-4135/LNBTS-4135/FTM-1/IPNO-1" 
"btsId">4135<  
distName="PLMN-PLMN/MRBTS-4138/LNBTS-4138/FTM-1/IPNO-1"
```

And in my final file I would like to have only lines like this:

```
MRBTS-4132,4132,10.52.71.38
```

So I would like to search only for lines where I have such pairs:

- first line has a distName
- second line has btsId
- third line has IpAddress

Lines with different sequence like:

- first distName
- second btsId
- third distName again

will be simply rejected.

I have currently such code:

```
grep -E "MRBTS|btsId|IpAddress" topology.xml > temp_list

id_list=(`grep -E "btsId" temp_list | grep -o '[0-9]*'`)

ip_list=(`grep -E "IpAddress" temp_list | grep -E -o "(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)"`)

id_size=${#id_list[*]}

for (( e=0; e<$id_size; e++  ))

do
    echo "MRBTS-${id_list[e]};${ip_list[e]}" >> id_list

done
```

But as you can see it's accepting some missing line sequences and I would like to avoid such scenario.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because StackOverflow is not a code writing service. What did you try?

Comment: Currently what I'm doing is:

Comment: show us your effort and we can help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After all it was much easier to use python for that solution with ElementTree library. The code is

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree
import os

HOME = os.environ['HOME']

with open(HOME+'/TF/topo/topo.xml', 'rt') as f:
    tree = ElementTree.parse(f)

for node in tree.findall('.//{raml20.xsd}managedObject'):
    btsId=None
    Ip=None
    for p in node.findall('{raml20.xsd}p'):
        if p.attrib.get('name')=='btsId':
            btsId=p.text
        elif p.attrib.get('name')=='IpAddress':
            Ip=p.text
    if btsId and Ip:
        print "MRBTS-"+btsId+";"+Ip
```

Answer (score 0):

With gawk:

```
awk -v RS='distName=' -F "[<>/]" 'NR!=1{print $2","$7","$10}' file.txt
```

Comment: You should mention that's gawk-specific due to the multi-char RS.